# How to avoid staying logged in on websites after I finish using them

Tags: firefox, login

I am looking for a way to find out on which sites I am logged in so I can avoid being logged in on sites that I don't use directly. (e.g. If now I check my Gmail for new emails, after an hour it is totally useless for me to be logged in on Google Search.).

I could log out manually but many times I know I want to log out (and stop using the website for a longer period of time) *after* I close the tab with that website, and if I don't have an open tab with the website, I am not sure if I am logged in or not. I have to open a tab with the website to check this.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really possible. It would be possible to list the sites that firefox has stored http authentication credentials for and sites for which you have had it store login credentials but that won't tell you if you are logged in currently or if the creds are good. Doing this for sites that firefox doesn't store anything for would require knowing about the various cookies/etc. that sites use to store session information (and still wouldn't be able to tell you that you hadn't been logged out since you were last there).

Comment: I understand, but I would be satisfied even if I had to set it up manually for the sites I use frequently in a way in which the add-on will monitor a cookie or the HTML contents of the website for something to dis/appear.

Comment: You can get logged out of a website without the cookie expiring locally. You can get logged out of a website while your local credentials are still good. You really don't want your add-on polling the website at intervals to check whether you can still log in. Why do you want this add-on?

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the add-on polling the website at intervals but letting me click on a button to poll the website at that moment. That would be ideal, but something similar would be OK. I would like this type of add-on for more privacy. For example, I don't like to see I am logged in every time I go to search something on Google just because a few hours ago I had to use another Google service.

Comment: Message for the moderators: I have reworded my question. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, websites identify you are logged in through some sort of session cookie.  There's other ways they may choose to do this as well.  There isn't a universal standard for session cookies.

So without specific knowledge of how the site uses its cookies or does logins, there isn't a way to automatically do this.  It would require collecting and maintaining a bunch of information and that's probably why there is no such add on.

There may be a cookie tool that shows you all unexpired cookies by last modified date.  Probably anything that's newer than an acceptable threshold (say 2 hours or so) would possibly represent what you're logged into - assuming a site deletes a cookie when you log out which sites may not do.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers have a secure mode (E.G. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> incognito mode in Google Chrome) and Firefox is no different:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info#w_what-does-private-browsing-not-save

Firefox privacy mode will not store cookies and other identifying information beyond the time the browser window is open. Log into a website in privacy mode, and when you are finished close the window and it should not maintain any connection information on your computer. Use this all the time, you'll never be left logged into a website.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the general case of websites that use a session cookie or local session storage it should be possible to have a browser extension which routinely polls either all the local storage or the local storage for a specified list of websites and forcibly removes any locally stored information after some amount of delay. I don't know if any such extensions exist at the moment or how much work it would be to write one but in theory it should be possible (assuming extensions have the ability to detect the things they need to to do this).